# How do I find the largest empty space in such images?

Tags: python, algorithm, opencv, image-processing

I would like to find the empty spaces (black regions) in images similar to the one I've posted below, where I have randomly sized blocks scattered in it.

[image]

By empty spaces, I refer to such possible open fields ( i have no particular lower bound on the area, but I would like to extract the top 3-4 largest ones present in the image.) There is also no restriction on the geometric shape they can take, but these empty spaces must not contain any of the blue blocks.

[image]

What is the best way to go about this?

What I've done till now:

My original image actually looks like this. I identified all the points, grouped them based on a certain distance threshold and applied a convex hull around them. I'm unsure how to proceed further. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Something like https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/323233.323255 ?

Comment: Yes, something like that but I approximate results are okay in my case.

Comment: I paraphrase, but you wrote something like, "there is ***no restriction*** on the geometric shape the black blobs can take so long as the black blobs do not contain a blue blob" If you want to find the largest black blob which does not contain any blue, then simply take the entire black region. The entire black background is a very strange shape, but it certainly contains no blue. If there are no restrictions, then viewing the black stuff as all one shape is allowed. I think you do have restrictions on which  geometric shapes are allowed, but you not know how to articulate those restrictions.

Comment: If you are looking for convex shapes, the problem is called “convex skull”, and the best known solution so far is O(n^7), with n the number of vertices in the input polygons. I think you are better off using the circular assumption from fmw42’s answer.

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon Thanks for the clarification, Yes I have some restrictions on the shape, in the sense that it has to be bordered , but I donot care if its an abstract polygon . Simply taking the entire black region is not applicable in my case.

Comment: I found a wikipedia article, that is similar to my problem, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Largest_empty_rectangle but I am not restricted to using a rectangle.

Comment: @VS: Your response to Samuel's question doesn't really answer it, because now I can ask, "What about the entire black region *minus the top-left pixel*?" Etc., etc. You need to describe a *category of allowed regions* such that a program, given an arbitrary region, could determine whether that region is allowed or not. A typical example might be "Only convex polygons are allowed" (except that can't be what you want here, since your example contains non-convex polygons). Separately, it's not clear to me what you mean by "bordered".

Comment: @VS For problems such as yours there are said to be "***infeasible***" solutions and "***feasible***" solutions. Some black-color blobs are ***good*** (feasible or allowed) and some black-color blobs are ***bad*** (infeasible or not allowed). In order to solve the problem, we must know which black blobs are allowed, and which ones are not allowed. I have no idea what it means for a shape to be "bordered." Every 2D shape I can think of has a "border."

Comment: I really wish someone would migrate this question to a branch of stack exchange which supports MathJax (***LaTeX*** formatting). Currently the question is posted to stack-overflow. stack overflow does not support the MathJax plu-in. To really answer their question, a fair bit of math is required. I doubt that there is a software package to solve this particular problem already.

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon Sorry for the vagueness, perhaps it would be better if I phrased it as enclosed regions of space, that form an n-polygon. For simplicity, convex polygons work fine. I believe the attached image on the wikipedia article represents it better than I can articulate. It represents only rectangles but I am not restricted to just 4 vertices.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is one way in Python/OpenCV using the distance transform to find the largest Euclidean distance between the Xs.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import skimage.exposure

# read image
img = cv2.imread('xxx.png')

# convert to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold to binary and invert so background is white and xxx are black
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
thresh = 255 - thresh

# add black border around threshold image to avoid corner being largest distance
thresh2 = cv2.copyMakeBorder(thresh, 1,1,1,1, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, (0))
h, w = thresh2.shape

# create zeros mask 2 pixels larger in each dimension
mask = np.zeros([h + 2, w + 2], np.uint8)

# apply distance transform
distimg = thresh2.copy()
distimg = cv2.distanceTransform(distimg, cv2.DIST_L2, 5)

# remove excess border
distimg = distimg[1:h-1, 1:w-1]

# get max value and location in distance image
min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(distimg)

# scale distance image for viewing
distimg = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(distimg, in_range='image', out_range=(0,255))
distimg = distimg.astype(np.uint8)

# draw circle on input
result = img.copy()
centx = max_loc[0]
centy = max_loc[1]
radius = int(max_val)
cv2.circle(result, (centx, centy), radius, (0,0,255), 1)
print('center x,y:', max_loc,'center radius:', max_val)

# save image
cv2.imwrite('xxx_distance.png',distimg)
cv2.imwrite('xxx_radius.png',result)

# show the images
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("thresh2", thresh2)
cv2.imshow("distance", distimg)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Distance Transform Image:

[image]

Region of Largest Distance to Xs:

[image]

Textual Information:

center x,y: (179, 352) radius: 92.5286865234375

Comment: They look a bit like Voronoi diagrams, I suppose that is not an coincident?

Comment: Correct.  From the documentation, "the function provides a very fast way to compute the Voronoi diagram for a binary image". See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga8a0b7fdfcb7a13dde018988ba3a43042. But in the distance image, you would have to threshold on the local maximum to get the Voronoi image edges

Comment: @fmw42 thank you very much! (belated) i noticed i accepted your answer but forgot to thank you! i was able to build upon this solution and it helped immensely with our research